# How to create a new project in AsciiDocFX app?

Tags: asciidocfx

I am trying to use AsciidocFX version 1.8.5 on macOS Ventura (13.5).

How do I create a new project, such as from the bundled Book template?

[The documentation](https://asciidocfx.com/) does not mention anything about creating a new project.

[The demo video](https://youtu.be/2goMtz_vdtM?t=86) linked by that documentation shows the use of a **Book > Sample Book** menu item to create a new project in a selected folder. The menu bar shown includes **View**, **Book**, and **About** menus.

But I see *no such menu bar* when I run AsciidocFX. The main window contains no such menus, nor does the main macOS menu bar contain those menus. The main macOS menu bar contains only a single menu named **AsciidocFX** with menu items only for hiding, showing, and quitting the app.

So how does one create a new project from a template in AsciidocFX?

FYI, the top of the main window looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not know where to find that missing menu bar. But I have a workaround: Context menu in the file-browser pane.

In that pane, [“right-click”](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/right-click-mh35853/mac) (use secondary mouse button) to display a contextual menu. There you will find a *New Template* menu item where you can choose *Asciidoc Book* to set up your new project.

[image: screenshot of context-menu in file-browser pane to create from template]

You will then see a *Create New Directory* dialog to make a folder for your new project.

[image: screenshot of Create new directory dialog box]

After that, you will see a full set of example files generated in that folder.